# iptables with transparent proxy, how to pass the user IP

Tags: centos, iptables, squid, transparent-proxy

I have a local transparent proxy, but my problem is that packets, when re-routed, have the router IP and not the user. These are the rules that I currently have in place:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s ! 192.168.1.231 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.231:3128
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.1.231 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.1
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.1.231 -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80 -j DROP
```

- 192.168.1.231 = proxy server (squid) + DNS server
- 192.168.1.1 = iptable/router (centOs)

Everything seems working, but the IP in the proxy LOG is always `192.168.1.1` instead of possibly `192.168.1.46` or `192.168.4.25`

this is important for me because I have different squid rules for `192.168.4.XX` (DHCP) vs `192.168.1.XX` or `192.168.2.XX` and it would really help me also with finding who is miss-using the internet.

Comment: You MUST avoid using SNAT :)

Comment: Thank you, but I do not know iptables, how would I do it without SNAT ?

Answer (score 2):

with this method you can avoid NAT packet alterations.

at iptables box

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 80 -s squid-box
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j MARK --set-mark 3 -p tcp --dport 80
ip rule add fwmark 3 table 2
ip route add default via squid-box dev eth1 table 2
```

at squid box

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

see here for more details
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html

Comment: Thank you, but the squid box need to have port 80 free for apache

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about my interpretation of your setup. But maybe the forwarding works like this:

```
# HTTP Forward (TCP Port 80)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 0/0 -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.231:3128
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -d 192.168.1.231 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.1.1 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT

# DNS Forward (TCP & UDP Port 53)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -s 0/0 -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.231:53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 0/0 -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.231:53
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -d 192.168.1.231 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s 192.168.1.1 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.1.1 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

So your setup looks like this: `clients` -> `router` -> `proxy`.
If traffic from `proxy` to `clients` flow through the `router`, you can simply remove the `SNAT` rule without breaking anything, since the `router` will see the reply packets and can do the necessary IP translation on them. If it's not the case, then you can add routes on the `proxy` toward the `clients` via the `router`, so we're back to case #1. If this is not possible, then you can also install a HTTP proxy on the `router`, which will inform your `proxy` of the original user's IP via an `X-Forwarded-for` header.

You can also use Pat's answer with a slight modification:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 ! -d $proxy_ip -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

This way only the redirected traffic gets redirected again to the squid proxy, and the apache running on the same server can be used normally.